# ANSI SQL for subtracting a day

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

Supporting both MySQL and SQL Server I need to subtract a number of days from a date. Can this be done with ANSI SQL or do I need to maintain two version of this?

Eg. I have this for MySQL:

```
SELECT
  CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL '30' DAY
FROM dual;
```

Comment: As far as I know SQL Server does not support ANSI intervals - but why don't you just try for yourself? Writing this question probably took longer than just running that statement in SQL Server.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/449182/sql-ansi-to-manage-datetime-values

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - I did try it myself before writing the question! The code example, is just what it is - an example of what I try to accomplish.

Comment: Don't both RDBMSs support DATEADD()?

Comment: I think it is called DATA_ADD for MySQL.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no publicly available version for the ANSI SQL 2003 specs, but no vendor fully support it to begin with. Any how, there are enough differences in the syntax between these two to write different code for each.

MySQL has a `DATE_ADD` function:

```
SELECT DATE_ADD(CURRENT_DATE, INTERVAL 30 DAY)
FROM dual;
```

SQL Server has a `DATEADD` function (without the underscore):

```
SELECT DATEADD(DAY, 30, CAST(GETDATE() AS date))
```

`GETDATE()` return both date & time. The cast strips the time portion off.

Comment: Thanks, for confirming me on this, and for the two examples of how to do it on both systems.